# How do I remove logic from getter/setter?

Tags: java, methods, getter-setter

I am working on a program with a lot of getter/setter methods. I have been told that I should do all of my logic outside of these methods, but I'm not sure where to put it. For example, when you might need to converting an int to string or appending a string.

I have an example below where the only piece that should be in the getter is "return posEntryMode;". What should I do with all of the other logic? Do I just put it before I call the method?

```
public String getPOSEntryMode ()
{
    StringBuilder pos = new StringBuilder();
    pos.append(getPanEntryMode());
    pos.append(getPinEntryCapability());
    posEntryMode = pos.toString();
    return posEntryMode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily the case that you should do all your logic outside of getter/setter methods.

### The main reason to do logic elsewhere is to avoid UNINTENDED CONSEQUENCES.

Consider the following example:

```
public class MyClass {
  private int x;
  private final String name;

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public String getName() {
    x++;
    return name;
  }
}
```

See what's happening here? You have a method that *gets a name*, but it **also** changes the value of `x`. Your code is now confusing to anyone who reads it later; the change of value of `x` is an unintended consequence.

---

All that said, the code in your question is *just fine.* The only thing I might do differently is *cache* the value of it, so you don't have to do the same `String` operations over and over. Specifically, if the values of `getPanEntryMode` and `getPinEntryCapability` **never change**, you can do this, which can make your code run faster:

```
private String cachedPOSEntryMode = null;

public String getPOSEntryMode ()
{
  if(cachedPOSEntryMode == null) {
    StringBuilder pos = new StringBuilder();
    pos.append(getPanEntryMode());
    pos.append(getPinEntryCapability());
    cachedPosEntryMode = pos.toString();
  }
  return posEntryMode;
}
```

Comment: A nice thing about getters and setters is that you can use this cache logic and reset the cache value in the `set` methods of any dependent variables (meaning they can change all they want).

Answer (score 0):

Angela, basically what that mean is:

have another method called calculatePOSEntryMode: and do something like below

```
private String calculatePOSEntryMode(){
    StringBuilder pos = new StringBuilder();
    pos.append(getPanEntryMode());
    pos.append(getPinEntryCapability());
    posEntryMode = pos.toString();
    return posEntryMode;
}

public String getPOSEntryMode ()
{
    return calculatePOSEntryMode();
}
```

Comment: The way you've written it, it seems completely pointless to have 2 functions here instead of just one. There may be some arguments for it, but you'll have to justify it in the answer. There are also way better ways of having 2 methods, such as making one `private` or using cache logic (sort of like durron's answer). I'd say `calculate` and `get` are also both misleading names - they don't just calculate or get, they assign it to the class variable as well (and `get` calculates as well, and `calculate` gets as well).

Comment: Yep, I agree with your point, I was just trying to make her understand what that means, perhaps I should have put more details in there and done it patiently instead of running to answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done having a private method which can be called from some init/constructor method,
which calls the setter method as shown below.This keeps the purpose of the setters and getters as it is and
the logic of building the string is separated as well. 
Again it depends on getPanEntryMode() & getPinEntryCapability() 
which should have been populated with their values by the time buildPOSEntryMode() is called.

private void buildPOSEntryMode(){

```
StringBuilder pos = new StringBuilder();
pos.append(getPanEntryMode());
pos.append(getPinEntryCapability());
String posEntryMode = pos.toString();
setPOSEntryMode(posEntryMode); //setter method
```

}

```
private void setPOSEntryMode(String posEntryMode){
posEntryMode = posEntryMode;

  }
 private String getPOSEntryMode(){
    return posEntryMode;
}
```